# Transfer files from rescue mode to another server (Windows) by using FTP?

Tags: backup, ftp, vps, rescue-mode

So I'm having a problem with kimsufi server. I was installing windows by using this command:

```
wget -O- ...url.../server.gz | gunzip | dd of=/dev/sda
```

And I messed up and accidentally ran that command on already existing windows installation, now I can't use RDP anymore, I guess it's all gone now, it somehow wrote over existing installation, even though it had 3% progress at downloading the image. All my important files were on different partition, not on primary where the OS was stored.

Is there a way to transfer all files to another server by using rescue mode ? Can I somehow get FTP server running in Kimsufi Linux rescue mode ? I am thinking of connecting to it from another server (windows), browse files and download/back up them.

I have tried to use WinSCP, but it shows only Linux directories. How can I browse windows partitions through WinSCP ?

Comment: I don't really understand your situation, but it sounds like you just need to identify and `mount` the applicable partition - after that, you should be able to use WinSCP

Comment: @steeldriver Could it be that after running that command it had overwritten my main partition and corrupted other partitions ? 

I ran lsblk command and it shows only 2 partitions 
`NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT`
`sda      8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk`
`├─sda1   8:1    0  500M  0 part`
`└─sda2   8:2    0 14.5G  0 part` Or it just shows linux partitions ?

Comment: Ah yes that may be the case - I hadn't noticed that your `dd` output was the whole device `/dev/sda` rather than a partition

Comment: I fixed it myself, for those having this problem, here's my answer/solution to this problem  - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325911/how-to-recover-overwritten-partition?noredirect=1#comment573529_325911